# Generic function to convert c++11 enum to underlying type or if not enum return itself

Tags: c++11, enums, type-conversion

Just as the title says, need this because im serializing values to std::ostringstream and don't wish to overload operator<<.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
template<typename E, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<E>::value>::type>
typename std::underlying_type<E>::type
underlyer(E e)
{ return static_cast<typename std::underlying_type<E>::type>(e); }

template<typename E, typename = typename std::enable_if<!std::is_enum<E>::value>::type>
E
underlyer(E const& e)
{ return e; }
```

Note:  this doesn't work in all circumstances; for instance, if you try `underlyer("Hello, world")` it will fail because you cannot return a C array by value.  One way around this is to have the non-enum case return a reference to the parameter passed in, but you have to be a bit careful when the "same" function returns a value in some cases and a reference in others.